# Is there any API to get the total cost for a particular resourceID in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get total cost consumed for a particular resourceID in AWS cost explorer.I am able to take monthly or daily usage cost using usage type, instance name & product code but I couldn't take using resourceID.

I referred this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) for calculating total cost based on usage type, instance type but I don't find any documentation to find any API for resourceID.

Comment: Hi, I couldnt find either. but you can give a try to Amazon Athena. You can run queries to get cost per resource id. Refer this link https://www.concurrencylabs.com/blog/aws-cost-reduction-athena/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup detailed billing in AWS which will dump all your usage details to csv files in an s3 bucket. You can read more about it on the [billing page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=eu-west-1#/preference). Afterwards you can check on on the following page:

> BILLING & COST MANAGEMENT->COST EXPLORER->MONTHLY SPEND by SERVICE
>   VIEW

You can also create tags for each of your clients then start receiving cost allocation reports that break down the per instance cost for each of the tags you set up.